# Webview won't communicate with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift3

I'm building my first iOS hybrid app and I'm having trouble getting JavaScript to execute a Swift 3 function. I'm not quite sure how to test what I'm doing but here is what I have so far.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    var webView: WKWebView?
    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()

     override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = userContentController

        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: config)
        userContentController.add(self, name: "iOS")

        let url = URL(string:"https://relate.lavishweb.com/account")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        _ = webView?.load(request)

        self.view = self.webView
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        webView?.evaluateJavaScript("window.settings.test()") { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(result!)
            } else {
                print("dookie")
            }
        }

        print("dookie2")

        // this never prints
    }
}
```

The Javascript:

```
if(window.webkit){
    ev.preventDefault();
    webkit.messageHandlers.iOS.getImage();

}

window.settings = {
    test(){
    $('[required="required"]')[0].placeholder = 'dookie'
},
```

The breakpoint is never hit when I use the debugger to test the `webView.evaluateJavaScript` function, and The placeholder on the app never changes. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering I found out that the value of buttons were not changing even when I was changing them on the server `html markup` so i realized that Safari was caching the js file to the browser(because I'm using virtual dom instead of html). After I deleted the app from my emulator and then re-initialized it I was able to get everything working.

I hope this helps someone!